# HTML suddenly rendering green checkmark differently

Tags: html

I wrote a little script that sends an email to Outlook.  I haven't touched the code in over a year.  I've been using &#10004 for the pretty green checkmark that looks like this:

[image]

But a few days ago the green checkmark started appearing as a simple black checkmark:

[image]

I haven't changed anything.

I'm an HTML novice.  I've googled everything I can think of but clearly I'm missing something.  Can anyone tell me what's occurring here?

Here is the line of html that adds one checkmark to each column:

```
<td style="padding: 8px;border: 1px solid #DDD;">&#10004;</td>
```

It's odd to me that the red X and white question marks still appear as they have.

Comment: https://www.codetable.net/decimal/10004 This is not a green checkmark by default... Did you change anything in the last few days? Any updates? Any updates to other parts of the code?

Comment: @cloned, I haven't touched this code in over a year.  It just suddenly started rendering as a black checkmark.  I've got my program running on a build agent every morning at 6am.  It pulls my code directly from our corp github.

Comment: Weird, I just looked back through several of these emails from a month, two months, four months ago... they're all black checkmarks now.  Now I'm really confused.  You can clearly see the green checkmark in my post above.  What's happening?

Comment: You use inline styles or include a css script?  If second maybe the styles not loaded properly.

Comment: Without any example HTML we can't really help you and only guess. Maybe an update of the OS? We don't know.

Comment: If these are emoticons rather than images the font used would be the problem I guess. Maybe you are using a webfont which is no longer available under that URL?

Comment: @cloned, added the line of html that displays the checkmark.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, this is an html email in Outlook but it used to also display green when I was  learning it on W3schools for HTML.  That's where I initially tried all of my html.

Comment: What font is Outlook using?  Is it different than the one it used to use?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, when I select the checkmark and check the font it says, "Segoe UI Symbol".   Apparently this is the font I specified: <table style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;">

Comment: It renders as a bold black checkmark on my machine, in Outlook.  https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2714

Comment: From [here](https://emojipedia.org/check-mark/): *"Previously shown in red on Samsung and green on Google and Microsoft. "*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes!  That was it!  What does this mean exactly?  Could Outlook have updated and no longer support it?  Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Well, there's nothing to support.  All font systems must conform to some standard for their displays, otherwise every system would look different.  Microsoft apparently decided to do the right thing and render it as a black, bold checkmark, as the specification indicates.

Comment: And if I'm honest, the green checkmark looks very 1990's.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I miss the 90's!